# How to group multidimensional array by sub-array value in and reassign keys in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, grouping

I looked at all the similar questions and samples (there are many) but still can't get this to work (though I think I am close).

I have an array of employee schedules pulled from a text file...

schedule.txt:

```
    123,Joe,20120208,0845,1645
    123,Joe,20120209,0800,1600
    456,Sue,20120208,0900,1700
    456,Sue,20120209,0700,1500
    ...
```

My code to generate the array is:

```
    $schedule = file_get_contents('./schedule.txt');
    $s = explode("\n", $schedule);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($s); $i++) {
        $s[$i] = explode(",", $s[$i]);
    }
    print_r($s);
```

Output is:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 123
                [1] => Joe
                [2] => 20120208
                [3] => 0845
                [4] => 1645
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 123
                [1] => Joe
                [2] => 20120209
                [3] => 0800
                [4] => 1600
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => 456
                [1] => Sue
                [2] => 20120208
                [3] => 0900
                [4] => 1700
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => 456
                [1] => Sue
                [2] => 20120209
                [3] => 0700
                [4] => 1500
            )
    )
```

I am instead trying to group employees by Id in a new multidimensional array with output like this:

```
    Array
    (
        [123] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Joe
                        [1] => 20120208
                        [2] => 0845
                        [3] => 1645
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Joe
                        [1] => 20120209
                        [2] => 0800
                        [3] => 1600
                    )
            )

        [456] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Sue
                        [1] => 20120208
                        [2] => 0900
                        [3] => 1700
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Sue
                        [1] => 20120209
                        [2] => 0700
                        [3] => 1500
                    )
            )
    )
```

I cannot for the life of me wrap my head around how to change my existing array into this new (different) output...
I am trying this but getting nowhere:

```
    $newArr = array();

    foreach($s as $k => $v) {
        if(!isset($newArr[$v[0]])) {
            $newArr[$v[0]] = array();
        }

        $newArr[$v[0]][] = array($v[0]);
    }
```

Though my output is now:

```
    Array
    (
        [123] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 123
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 123
                    )
            )

        [456] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 456
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 456
                    )
            )
    )
```

Any thoughts? I know I am missing something in my code around the line:

```
    $newArr[$v[0]][] = array($v[0]);
```

I tried changing it to:

```
    $newArr[$v[0]][] = array(0 => $v[1], 1 => $v[2], 2 => $v[3], 3 => $v[4]);
```

which gives my the right output, but I now get undefined offset errors. Plus, if the number of keys in the sub array changes, this code is now limited to the 4 I explicitly entered...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should be enough, if I understood you right :)

```
$lines = file('./schedule.txt');

$employees = array();
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
    $chunks = explode(',', $line);
    $employees[$chunks[0]][] = array_slice($chunks, 1);
}

print_r($employees);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a function called [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) to easily grab comma separated values.  No need to do it yourself.

This code also solves your problem and properly handles blank lines:

```
if (($handle = fopen("schedules.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {

    $schedules = array();
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
        if ($data[0] !== null) { //blank lines return an array containing null
            $schedules[$data[0]][] = array_slice($data, 1);
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);

    //do what you need to

} else {
    // file failed to open
}
```

Note that I named the file `.csv` instead of `.txt`.  I'd recommend that you save things that are comma separated values as `.csv` files.  Maybe even define what each column is in the file as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
//read the file into an array with each line being an entry
$schedule = file('./schedule.txt');
//empty array
$s = array();
//loop through file lines
foreach($schedule as $row){
    //explode on comma
    $row = explode(",", trim($row));
    //if the id doesn't exist yet...
    if(!isset($s[$row[0]])){
        //...make it an empty array
        $s[$row[0]] = array();
    }
    //add the row under the id
    $s[$row[0]][] = $row;
}
print_r($s);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`fscanf`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fscanf.php):

```php
$handle    = fopen('./schedule.txt', 'r');
$employees = array();
while ($line = fscanf($handle, '%d,%s')) {
  $employees[$line[0]][] = explode(',', $line[1]);
}
fclose($handle);

print_r($employees);
```